# Entity framework 4.1 with one to many navigation how to prevent cyclic loading of related entities?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Entity framework 4.1 with one to many navigation how to  prevent cyclic loading of related entities ?

Ex: Two table have one to many relation

`event` and `discount`

Each `event` can have multiple `discount`s.

When I create a discount entity object I get the object of event with lazy loading.
With event object I get the collection of related discounts and the cycle continue.

I am sure the performance will reduce if the data is large with this kind of loading.

How to handle such situation in Entity framework.

```
public Event()
{
  public virtual ICollection<discount> discounts{ get; set; }    
}

public Discount
{    
  public virtual Event Event {get;set;}    
}
```

Another ex:

```
 [Bind(Exclude = "AlbumId")]
public class Album
  {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Genre")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }        

  }


   public partial class Genre
  {
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
  }


 public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a => a.Artist);
            return View(albums.ToList());
        }



   @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Truncate(item.Artist.Name, 25)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Truncate(item.Title, 25)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AlbumId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AlbumId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AlbumId })
        </td>
    </tr>
   }
```

In above ex. Albums has included Genre.So Album have genre and then genre has album list and it continues.Will it increase the size of dbcontext or will reduce performance. Is this the Wrong way to deal with loading of related navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we are using Entity Framework code first.   You would have two POCO classes; event and discount that would map onto tables of the same names.

```
public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        this.Discounts = new HashSet<Discount>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }
}

public class Discount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

}
```

and then you would have a class that inherits from DBContext

```
public class ExampleContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Discount> Discount { get: set; }
}
```

In order to access discounts by event where EventId = 1

```
var db = new ExampleContext();

var discounts = db.Discounts.Where(d => d.EventId == 1);
```

If you have an event object, you can access a discount by event as follows

```
var event = db.Events.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);

var discount = db.Entry(discount).Reference(d => d.Event).Load();
```

I dont think you will have any issues with cyclic loading of entities if you take a similar approach.  I hope this helps!

Edit:  Your code first approach with Genre and Album appears to be correct.  Assuming you have set up your POCO classes and your DbContext class correctly, performance is then determined by how you write your LINQ queries.   Good LINQ queries generate good SQL code.  Bad LINQ Queries generate bad SQL code.  LINQPad

[http://www.linqpad.net](http://www.linqpad.net/)

is a fantastic FREE tool for writing linq queries and examing the SQL code they generate and the results of a query.   For example

```
var albums = db.Albums;
```

generates the equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM Albums;
```

You should rarely return all the records in an entity or table.  On the other hand

```
var albums = db.Albums.Where(a => a.GenreId == 1).ToList();
```

Will generate something like

```
SELECT * FROM Albums
WHERE GenreId = 1;
```

which returns only a subset of the Albums table.

Comment: Thanks @wayne.blackmon! Should we need to turn off the lazy loading for that in DbContext as ` Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` and also should we need to remove Virtual from the properties shown above?

Comment: You should mark all association properties as virtual.  I dont think lazy loading is the issue.   I would have to see your linq code to see what the problem is.  I prefer not to walk association properties in LINQ code.  Each time you hit one, it will populate.   Try using a record ID or some other criteria in your lambda expression as shown above.

Comment: In above ex. Albums has included Genre.So Album have genre and then genre has album list and it continues.Will it increase the size of dbcontext or will reduce performance. Is this the Wrong way to deal with loading of related navigation properties?

Comment: I dont think the problem is lazy loading.  To answer your question, try to focus on writing efficient LINQ queries.  LINQPad can help a lot with that!